# how to refresh an incremental cube in microstrategy between two dates by replace option

Tags: filter, replace, refresh, cube, microstrategy

while we are trying to refresh an incremental cube daily using refresh option "replace" and for last 7 months filter which is defined as Postgresql statement using applysimple command :

```
"SELECT TO_char(current_date-INTERVAL '7 months','yyyymm')::numeric"
```

This filter gives the following error:

```
"Error: Invalid logical functions used in filter. Filter functions can only be Equal, And, Or and Not.

Error in Process method of Component: QueryEngineServer, Project XXXX, Job 3648, Error Code= -2147212264."
```

How can we handle this dynamic refresh logic? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incremental Cube Refresh object does not allow usage of ApplySimple method for updates using "replace" method, the filter has to be created at **Public Objects > Filters** and for creating a time filter, a driving attribute of the report (if the report is about orders, an attribute like "order_date" ) should be chosen.